# When I add a javascript object to an array their properties changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this type of object:

```
//This is a single cell
{
  state: 0,
  row: 0,
  col: 0
}
```

And I want to have: An array of arrays (board states) of arrays (rows of the board) of cells (columns)  but when I add a new row to the board states array every column is changed to 59 whit no reason (59 is the max possible column and 24 is the maximum row).

```
let board = this.cells //Actuall board
  let newBoards = []//Array of all the boards
  let cellNeighbors //Save the number of neighbors of x cell
  let rowOfCells = [] // An array whit a row of cells
  let newCell


    newBoards.push([])
    for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
      newCell = {state: 0, row: 0, col: 0} //A new cell to push into an array

      for(let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
      {  
        newCell.row = i 
        newCell.col = j

        cellNeighbors = countNeighbors(i, j, board)

        // Apply rules to cell
        newCell.state = rulesAply(cellNeighbors, board[i][j].state)
        // Add new cells to an array
        rowOfCells.push(newCell)
        // Set timeout for make a steps animation of every state in the array
      }
      newBoards[0].push(rowOfCells)
      rowOfCells = []
    }
console.log(newBoards)
```

My output is something like this:

```
[Array(24)]
0: Array(24)
0: Array(60)
0: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
1: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
2: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
3: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
4: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
5: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
6: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
7: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
8: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
9: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
10: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
11: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
12: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
13: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
14: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
15: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
16: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
17: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
18: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
19: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
20: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
21: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
22: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
23: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
24: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
25: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
26: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
27: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
28: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
29: {state: 0, row: 0, col: 59}
```

and continues with every row, and each col always is 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only create a `newCell` in the outer loop, so when you `.push` it in the inner loops, you're pushing the *same object* in memory to the array multiple times. Create the object inside the inner loop instead:

```
for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  const rowOfCells = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
    const newCell = { state: 0, row: i, col: j };
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    cellNeighbors = countNeighbors(i, j, board)

    // Apply rules to cell
    newCell.state = rulesAply(cellNeighbors, board[i][j].state)
    // Add new cells to an array
    rowOfCells.push(newCell)
    // Set timeout for make a steps animation of every state in the array
  }
  newBoards.push(rowOfCells);
}
```

(pretty sure you wanted to push the new row of cells to the new `newBoards` array, not to its first child)

Or, with array methods instead:

```
const newBoards = board.map((rowArr, row) => (
  row.map((oldCell, col) => (
    { row, col, state: countNeighbors(row, col, board) }
  ))
));
```

Comment: Wow thank  you, I don't know why it was taking to long to solve for me

Comment: Nitpick, but the `row` and `col` properties seem a bit imprecise - when seeing a variable or property with that name, I first think that it holds a *collection* of multiple cells. You might consider changing them to something like `rowIndex`, maybe. (precise variable names can prevent bugs, and make code more readable)